# python webscraping with selenium: trouble locating modal element

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

I want to go to http://ted.com/talks, click the "See All Topics" in the "Topics" dropdown, and then click the a random letter heading, like "C" or "D-E". However, I don't know how to find the element in the modal popup for that specific letter heading.

This is what the letter heading elements look like when I click "Inspect Element":

```
<li class="topic-select__range">
  <a class = "topic-select__range__link" href="#" data-index="0">A-B</a>
</li>
<li class="topic-select__range">
  <a class = "topic-select__range__link" href="#" data-index="1">C</a>
</li>
<li class="topic-select__range">
  <a class = "topic-select__range__link" href="#" data-index="2">D-E</a>
</li>

... etc.
```

My program can get all the way to See All Topics just fine but gets Cannot Locate Element Error when I try to click on the letter headers. This is what my code snippet looks like so far:

```
# Each header is assigned a number. A header is picked at random, and clicked. 
# [ERROR: Cannot locate element.]
random_letter = random.randint(0, 8)
topics_window = browser.find_element_by_class_name("select-modal__content topic-select") # error here, when program tries to find modal popup or tags within it
letter_headers = topics_window.find_element_by_class_name("topic-select__range__link")
letter_headers[random_letter].click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a way to access modal JavaScript content with selenium. I have instead found a way to do so using web API.